# Are there languages without T-V distinction (but with two pronouns, one exclusive to singular, the other to plural)?

Tags: pronouns, person

What I mean is modern English only has "you" for any number of individuals.

French (my native language) has *tu* that is exclusive to a single person, *vous* is mostly used for at least two people, but it is sometimes formally used for a single person (especially a stranger, or an elderly person, or a politician such as a monarch/a president/a prime minister/an autocrat/a mayor).

So, are there any real-life languages that do not have T-V distinction, but with two pronouns (one always refers to a single person, the other always refers to a group of people)?

Comment: As Draconis said, there are many examples. Hebrew has different pronouns for second person depending on number and gender, and using the plural version for a single person just sounds wrong and carries no implication of formality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure. Latin has *tu* and *vōs*, Swahili has *wewe* and *ninyi*, Hittite has *zik* and *sumes*, Ancient Greek has *sŷ* and *hymeîs*, Akkadian has *atta/atti* and *attunu/attina*…

Outside the Standard Average European sprachbund, it's quite common to have separate singular and plural pronouns, without them being involved in a formality distinction.

Comment: even within SAE (not even especially peripheral members) you have Spanish (both tu/vosotros in Spain, and tu/vos in voseo areas of Latin America) and German (du/ihr, although I believe in common usage formal Sie is more common than ihr these days). Old & Early Middle English too (þū > thou, ġē > ye > you which only acquired a T-V distinction in Later Middle English)

Comment: I wonder, why the Ancient Greek and Hettite are so similar? The both plural versions come from PIE *sumios? I have never heard of this pronoun.

Comment: Yiddish (which is a High German dialect, thus a peripheral SAE) has only _du_ and _ir_ (sg/pl). No honorifics in the second person. Of course Jewish life in Europe was not court life.

Comment: AFAIK Irish uses  _tú_ and _sibh_ purely to distinguish number, _sibh_ is never used as a polite singular.

Comment: @jlawler Jewish life was quite often a part of court life. There is even a term "court Jew". This does not mean of course that it should affect the language usage to any notable extent.

Comment: @ColinFine Correct, unlike Scottish, which does use _sibh_ as polite singular.

Comment: @Tristan Like German, however, Spanish does have a T-V distinction – it’s just based on third-person pronouns (_usted(es)_). Icelandic is sort of similar: in the singular there’s only _þú_, but in the plural there’s unmarked _þið_ and honorific (rare) _þér_, so there’s sort of a T-V distinction, but only in the plural – but on the other hand, also in the first person plural, where _við_ is unmarked and _vér_ is honorific/elevated/hyper-formal.

Comment: @Anixx PIE pronouns are a minefield, but both forms are generally taken back to a common proto-form _*us-u̯é-_ or _*us-mé-_ (with a secondary plural marker _*-s_ added). The shape of the suffix as _*-u̯é-_ or _*-mé-_ is a tangled mess of disagreements, but the ‘normal’ _*us-_ form of the pronoun itself for both forms is relatively agreed upon. The Greek form is regular (_*us-mé-es_ > _*hȳ-méis_), while the Hittite form involves either metathesis (_*usm-_ > _*sum-_) or, as favoured by Katz (1998), aphaeresis + Lindeman variant (_*usu̯é_ > _*su̯é_ > _*suu̯é_ > _*sumé_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that is a formality distinction, but not a T-V distinction. A T-V distinction is only when there are two pronouns, a singular informal pronoun, and a plural or formal pronoun

Comment: @Tristan That is not how I’ve ever seen the term used, nor how any of the books I have available here define it. Their definitions all line up with Wikipedia’s, that it is “the contextual use of different pronouns […] to convey formality or familiarity”, regardless of whether those pronouns are distributed be exactly as in Late Latin where the name comes from or in other ways. That is also how Brown and Gilman who coined the term use it (they include Spanish _usted_, Italian _lei_ and German _Sie_ as V forms).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet huh, looks like you're correct that the term is commonly used in this broader sense. No idea why I only had this stricter sense in my head